# How to return taxonomy term list from all active facet filters on page and use this list as contextual filter in block of usual views

Tags: views, search

Please need help. (not solr)

I have views facet page (list of users) with facet filters by fields (taxonomy terms) in this page -> i need to past usual views block (with nodes) in this page with contextual filter as taxonomy terms taken from active facet filters of page.

How to do this?